# JOIN two tables, return only first

Tags: join, left-join

Any way to improve this code? I am trying to display all columns from B at the same time one other column from C based on file name matching between B and C

```
SELECT B.filename, B.request_num, B.attachment_name, 
B.date_time, B.received_date, B.ID, C.station_code
FROM B_attachments B
JOIN  C_fact C ON C.filename = B.filename
WHERE C.station_code LIKE '%OAK%'
```

What I'm asking is if there's anyway I can perhaps use SELECT * in this instead of writing out all the column names. Using SELECT * returns all column from B AND C. I just want B and one column from C. I need this as I will be copying this code for other tables that have a lot more columns than B. Using LEFT JOIN did not help me either.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT B.*, C.station_code
FROM ...
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B.*, C.station_code
FROM B_attachments B
JOIN  C_fact C ON C.filename = B.filename
WHERE C.station_code LIKE '%OAK%'
```

This ought to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think this meets your spec ("use `SELECT *` instead of writing out all the column names", "improve the code"):

```
SELECT *
  FROM B_attachments
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT filename, station_code
           FROM C_fact
          WHERE station_code LIKE '%OAK%' ) C;
```